I need to remove an outlet but it has wires that are running to lights in that room and another outlet. How do I remove the outlet and rewire


I removed an outlet and need to do away with it but it has lights and another outlet on the chain how do I wire the outlet wires to existing wires in the box?

I have tried that and it still doesn’t work. Also do I just cap off the ground wire that was on the outlet. I have checked the other outlets in the chain and I had to replace GFCI in the bathroom and that helped the outlets in the chain work but the power stops at the outlet that was removed. It had power before I removed it. I will send pictures tomorrow

If it "doesn't work", your connections are wrong or bad. Update the question with a photo of the wiring and folks may be able to point out the error. It would be better to also include a photo of how it was wired before you messed with it, but I'm betting you didn't take one.

Hi! You were unable to leave this as a comment because you have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please consider registering one of them then merge them together, which will allow you to edit, comment on any of your posts and accept an answer on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

You cannot make the box inaccessible.  It must be remain accessible without tools.  So a door/table/sofa is okay.  Drywall is not okay.
With outlets/receptacles it is easy wiring.  Blacks to blacks, whites to whites and grounds to grounds.  This is for the the common setups.
If you have red wires or have the tabs between the screws missing, post pictures to your question.
